# Native API into Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: api, native, thunderbird

I am making an application and would like for this application to be able to retrieve data from Mozilla Thunderbird. However, I have only been able to find an API for Thunderbird *extensions*. Is there an API that will allow native applications, *outside* of Thunderbird to interact with Thunderbird's databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you could create a Thunderbird extension and communicate with it via TCP sockets (see [`nsIServerSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIServerSocket)). That extension would do the "dirty work" for you. If you want to get the data while Thunderbird isn't running then the only solution will be redoing the database reading logic in your application (Thunderbird is open-source of course but reusing its code will be hard). Btw, the `.msf` files use the infamous [Mork file format](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mork).